# Entering birth date using sliders with Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've tried getting birth date functionality to appear as sliders as seen here https://www.facebook.com to work. There are sliders for month day and year and I'm trying to emulate them. time_field_tag did not work.
**Could someone please tell me the best way to get month day and year sliders working in ruby on rails?**

By the way, I'm trying to model face book's homepage as a programming exercise, which is where these questions are coming from. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you're talking about registration frame with 3 dropdown elements (day / month/ year).The Facebook realization is not perfect. For example you can select nonexistent dates like 31 / February. So they did not worry about. If you will follow their's path, the simpliest realization can be like this:

```
# For date
select_tag :day, options_for_select((1..31).to_a) # populate array using range

# For month
select_tag :month, options_for_select([ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ... ])

# For year
select_tag :year, options_for_select((1900..2014).to_a)
```